# display email on web page using ruby on rails and Mail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I am working an application that sort of acts as a web based email client.  I'm using this gem to receive emails so i can display them on a webpage:

https://github.com/mikel/mail

I get the emails fine but many times they come out with a lot of gibberish.  For example, i get html code that didnt parse, or extra = signs in the html.  Other emails come out fine.  Does anyone know how to ensure that the html part of the email is stripped of all the gibberish mail clients use so i can display on a webpage?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rabisuz/sanitize) to strip all HTML tags, or all but a few you want to leave (such as links).